# How to combine each elements in set of dictionary in a list to other set of dictionary list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

suppose if two dictionary list are

```
l1 = [{'name': '1st Match - Sri Lanka v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': '2nd Match - Bangladesh v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': '3rd Match - Sri Lanka v Bangladesh', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': '4th Match - Sri Lanka v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': '5th Match - Bangladesh v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': '6th Match - Sri Lanka v Bangladesh', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': 'Final - TBC v TBC', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}]
l2 = [{'date': 'Tue Mar 6'}, {'date': 'Thu Mar 8'}, {'date': 'Sat Mar 10'}, {'date': 'Mon Mar 12'}, {'date': 'Wed Mar 14'}, {'date': 'Fri Mar 16'}, {'date': 'Sun Mar 18'}]
```

I want to combine element in l2 to elements of l1 like as follow.

```
 L3 = [{'name': '1st Match - Sri Lanka v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo','date': 'Tue Mar 6'}, {'name': '2nd Match - Bangladesh v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo','date': 'Thu Mar 8'}, {'name': '3rd Match - Sri Lanka v Bangladesh', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo','date': 'Sat Mar 10'}, {'name': '4th Match - Sri Lanka v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo','date': 'Mon Mar 12'}, {'name': '5th Match - Bangladesh v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo','date': 'Wed Mar 14'}, {'name': '6th Match - Sri Lanka v Bangladesh', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo','date': 'Fri Mar 16'}, {'name': 'Final - TBC v TBC', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo','date': 'Sun Mar 18'}]
```

which function can I use to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Comment: No. It is not the case here.

Comment: Yeah, it's different, this is a list containing dictionary

Comment: There are several correct answers, please accept one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res = [{**x, **y} for x, y in zip(l1, l2)]
```

Comment: your answer worked for me thanks, for others I was getting TypeError: 'ResultSet' object is not callable

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way:

```
l1 = [{'name': '1st Match - Sri Lanka v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': '2nd Match - Bangladesh v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': '3rd Match - Sri Lanka v Bangladesh', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': '4th Match - Sri Lanka v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': '5th Match - Bangladesh v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': '6th Match - Sri Lanka v Bangladesh', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': 'Final - TBC v TBC', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}]
l2 = [{'date': 'Tue Mar 6'}, {'date': 'Thu Mar 8'}, {'date': 'Sat Mar 10'}, {'date': 'Mon Mar 12'}, {'date': 'Wed Mar 14'}, {'date': 'Fri Mar 16'}, {'date': 'Sun Mar 18'}]

res = [{**d[0],**d[1]} for d in zip(l1,l2)]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': '1st Match - Sri Lanka v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo', 'date': 'Tue Mar 6'}, {'name': '2nd Match - Bangladesh v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo', 'date': 'Thu Mar 8'}, {'name': '3rd Match - Sri Lanka v Bangladesh', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo', 'date': 'Sat Mar 10'}, {'name': '4th Match - Sri Lanka v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo', 'date': 'Mon Mar 12'}, {'name': '5th Match - Bangladesh v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo', 'date': 'Wed Mar 14'}, {'name': '6th Match - Sri Lanka v Bangladesh', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo', 'date': 'Fri Mar 16'}, {'name': 'Final - TBC v TBC', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo', 'date': 'Sun Mar 18'}]
```

You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression#26853961) to see how to merge dictionaries.

Comment: you don't need `list(zip(l1, l2))`. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This should help.

```
l1 = [{'name': '1st Match - Sri Lanka v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': '2nd Match - Bangladesh v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': '3rd Match - Sri Lanka v Bangladesh', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': '4th Match - Sri Lanka v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': '5th Match - Bangladesh v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': '6th Match - Sri Lanka v Bangladesh', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': 'Final - TBC v TBC', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}]
l2 = [{'date': 'Tue Mar 6'}, {'date': 'Thu Mar 8'}, {'date': 'Sat Mar 10'}, {'date': 'Mon Mar 12'}, {'date': 'Wed Mar 14'}, {'date': 'Fri Mar 16'}, {'date': 'Sun Mar 18'}]

l3 = []
for i in zip(l1, l2):
    val = i[0]
    val.update((i[1]))
    l3.append(val)
print l3
```

**Output:**

```
[{'date': 'Tue Mar 6', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo', 'name': '1st Match - Sri Lanka v India'}, {'date': 'Thu Mar 8', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo', 'name': '2nd Match - Bangladesh v India'}, {'date': 'Sat Mar 10', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo', 'name': '3rd Match - Sri Lanka v Bangladesh'}, {'date': 'Mon Mar 12', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo', 'name': '4th Match - Sri Lanka v India'}, {'date': 'Wed Mar 14', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo', 'name': '5th Match - Bangladesh v India'}, {'date': 'Fri Mar 16', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo', 'name': '6th Match - Sri Lanka v Bangladesh'}, {'date': 'Sun Mar 18', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo', 'name': 'Final - TBC v TBC'}]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
l1 = [{'name': '1st Match - Sri Lanka v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': '2nd Match - Bangladesh v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': '3rd Match - Sri Lanka v Bangladesh', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': '4th Match - Sri Lanka v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': '5th Match - Bangladesh v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': '6th Match - Sri Lanka v Bangladesh', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'name': 'Final - TBC v TBC', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}]
l2 = [{'date': 'Tue Mar 6'}, {'date': 'Thu Mar 8'}, {'date': 'Sat Mar 10'}, {'date': 'Mon Mar 12'}, {'date': 'Wed Mar 14'}, {'date': 'Fri Mar 16'}, {'date': 'Sun Mar 18'}]
print(list(zip(l1,l2)))
l3=[]
for i in zip(l1,l2):
 d=i[0] 
 d.update(i[1]) 
 l3.append(d)
print(l3)
```

> i[0] is {'name': '1st Match - Sri Lanka v India', 'place': 'R
>   Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}
>
> i[1] is {'date': 'Tue Mar 6'}

Output for

```
print(list(zip(l1,l2)))
```

> [({'name': '1st Match - Sri Lanka v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa
>   Stadium, Colombo'}, {'date': 'Tue Mar 6'}), ({'name': '2nd Match -
>   Bangladesh v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'},
>   {'date': 'Thu Mar 8'}), ({'name': '3rd Match - Sri Lanka v
>   Bangladesh', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'date': 'Sat
>   Mar 10'}), ({'name': '4th Match - Sri Lanka v India', 'place': 'R
>   Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'date': 'Mon Mar 12'}), ({'name': '5th
>   Match - Bangladesh v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'},
>   {'date': 'Wed Mar 14'}), ({'name': '6th Match - Sri Lanka v
>   Bangladesh', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo'}, {'date': 'Fri
>   Mar 16'}), ({'name': 'Final - TBC v TBC', 'place': 'R Premadasa
>   Stadium, Colombo'}, {'date': 'Sun Mar 18'})]

```
print(l3)
```

> [{'name': '1st Match - Sri Lanka v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa
>   Stadium, Colombo', 'date': 'Tue Mar 6'}, {'name': '2nd Match -
>   Bangladesh v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo', 'date':
>   'Thu Mar 8'}, {'name': '3rd Match - Sri Lanka v Bangladesh', 'place':
>   'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo', 'date': 'Sat Mar 10'}, {'name': '4th
>   Match - Sri Lanka v India', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo',
>   'date': 'Mon Mar 12'}, {'name': '5th Match - Bangladesh v India',
>   'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo', 'date': 'Wed Mar 14'},
>   {'name': '6th Match - Sri Lanka v Bangladesh', 'place': 'R Premadasa
>   Stadium, Colombo', 'date': 'Fri Mar 16'}, {'name': 'Final - TBC v
>   TBC', 'place': 'R Premadasa Stadium, Colombo', 'date': 'Sun Mar 18'}]

Comment: Oh! its simple as that thanks @jayshankargupta, is this the effective way to do or there any other method to do?

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP wants 'name', 'place' and 'date' in the same dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

Code:

```
L3 = [dict(a.items() + b.items()) for a,b in zip(L1,L2)]
```